# Component not rendering in headerTitle

Tags: react-native, expo

My HomeHeader component is not rendering within the headerTitle. I am expecting to render since when I do it as a direct string it shows up in the headerTitle.

```
const HomeHeader = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
    <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerTitle: HomeHeader}} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ChatRoom" component={ChatRoomScreen} options={{ headerShown: true }} />
    
      

      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: 'Oops!' }} />
      <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
      </Stack.Group>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Please see the HomeHeader component up top and then it is currently within the headerTitle of my home screen.

Comment: if you pass only a string to headerTitle like headerTitle: 'Home' , does it show up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some size to the View and some style to the text maybe ...